# How can I customize this Google Bar Chart?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-visualization

Here is a google bar chart I am creating:
http://jsfiddle.net/nGvdB/

I read up on the Google Bar Chart documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart.html) but I just cannot figure out how to customize this chart. Specifically, I want this:

On the horizontal axis, I see numbers 0,1,2,3,4. I want the graph only to go from 0 to 3. I have `hAxis.maxValue` set to 3 but it still shows till 4. None of my data is greater than

Instead of the horizontal axis labels reading `{0,1,2,3}` I want it to read `{'','Low','Med','High'}`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it always adds 1 to the highest value. Try using `maxValue: 2` and for the data value use `2.999999` instead of `3`. It's a hack, though.

Comment: That did do the trick but it now shows the horizontal axis values in intervals of 0.75 `{0.0,0.75,1.50,2.25,3.00}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using google charts API is quite difficult there is useful jquery library that simplifies the issue http://keith-wood.name/gChart.html