# How to label Google Column Chart bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization, jqplot

I am using [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) to create chart for values which goes from 1 to millions.

**Problem**
The bars which are representing smaller values (ex: less than 50 or so) are invisible on graph and no way I can see what values correspond to certain x-axis.

This would be solved if I can somehow print y-axis values on top of bars.But, I couldn't find any mention in the API doc on how to do it.

There is similar problem here, but it doesn't answers my question.

[put labels on top of inside bar in google interactive bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871729/put-labels-on-top-of-inside-bar-in-google-interactive-bar-chart)

There are some other more than year old unanswered questions here, I am hoping someone might have found a solution or **a workaround** by now, that is why asking this question again.

[Google Visualization: Column Chart, simple question but can't find the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409060/google-visualization-column-chart-simple-question-but-cant-find-the-answer)

[How to show values on the the top of columns Google Chart API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098322/how-to-show-values-on-the-the-top-of-columns-google-chart-api)

Can you show me how to achieve what I want using [How can I customize this Google Bar Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412385/how-can-i-customize-this-google-bar-chart) ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out Andrew Gallant's JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/QjQNX/

It uses a clever hack of a combo chart to accomplish what I think you're looking for.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});

  data.addRows([
    ['Foo', 53, 'Foo text'],
    ['Bar', 71, 'Bar text'],
    ['Baz', 36, 'Baz text'],
    ['Cad', 42, 'Cad text'],
    ['Qud', 87, 'Qud text'],
    ['Pif', 64, 'Pif text']
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, 1, 2]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(view, {
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    series: {
      0: {
        type: 'bars'
      },
      1: {
        type: 'line',
        color: 'grey',
        lineWidth: 0,
        pointSize: 0,
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      maxValue: 100
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for link. I found another work around, just use the log scale to show y axis values `vAxis:{logScale:true}`

Comment: Is there a way to make in different colors between different. for example if it between 40 and 80 red, and if is 80 or higher make it yellow?

Comment: what if i want label on any one bar and others should be empty without any line. http://jsfiddle.net/z05kfm8b/

Answer (score 4):

I had some setbacks using annotation and the invisible line (for example, having it displayed in the tooltip as another series).

I've made a hack to the `ComboChart` (could work with `BarChart` and `ColumnChart` as well, with a couple of changes) to insert the labels into the SVG.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/augustomen/FE2nh/

Tested on Firefox 21, Chrome 27 and IE 9.