# google bar charts bars missing - big difference in values

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm doing a graph using google bar charts to show sales revenue for branches all over the world.

Revenue is displayed in various currencies. Sometimes there is a big difference in the numbers due to some weaker currencies that ridiculously low Eg 1 billion zim dollar = 1 USD.

So when bars shows, you will see massive bar for zim dollar and cannot see the USD one... If you hover over the USD key on the right of the graph it highlight the small line that represents USD

But there is no way to hover over the bar itself to at least see the value. it's just too small... like 1 pixel or even less.

Is there a way to set a min height of the bar so that at least one can hover over it?

Comment: have you tried adjusting the `viewWindow` of the axis? you could specify `hAxis.viewWindow.max` and `min` to reduce the range displayed, which should increase the size of the bar...

Comment: i tried the minValue, maxValue, viewWindow options.. but none helped.
in the end i went with the { role: 'annotation' } option, which at least showed the label for user to see

Comment: another option is also to use the vAxis:{logScale:true}...

see Watt's comment on the accepted answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047650/how-to-label-google-column-chart-bars